# Android Async Task Completion

Tags: android, mobile, android-asynctask

I the code blow.
And I need to call execute within a loop.
Problem is I need the loop to pause while execute is completing and then continue.
The loop runs but it calls execute immediately, which causes the files not be to downloaded.

```
private class DownloadVerses extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        try {
            //Thread.sleep(5000);
            if(Utils.downloadFile(params[0])){
                int progressPercentage = Integer.parseInt(params[2]);
                downloadProgress.setProgress(progressPercentage);
                return "Downloading: "+params[1];

            }
            else{
                return "ERROR Downloading: "+params[1];
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Thread.interrupted();
            return "ERROR Downloading: "+params[1];
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if(result.contains("ERROR")){
            downloading.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f05036"));

        }
        else{
            downloading.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#79a1ad"));

        }

        downloading.setText(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

And I am currently trying:

```
DownloadVerses download = new DownloadVerses();

  int i = 0;
  while(i < verseTitles.size()){

      String progressString = String.valueOf(progress);

      if(download.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
          download.execute(Mp3s.get(i), Titles.get(i),progressString);


              if(progress < 100){

                  if((progress + increment) > 100){
                      progress = 100;
                  }
                  else{
                      progress += increment;
                  }

              }
              i++;
      }     
}
```

Comment: do you need to download multiple file in a queue in a single task

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line...

```
DownloadVerses download = new DownloadVerses();
```

And every time create a new object of `DownloadVerses` to execute a new `AsyncTask`...This procedure will not stop any `AsyncTask` from execution and it will allow every `AsyncTask` to execute independently.

```
new DownloadVerses().execute(Mp3s.get(i), Titles.get(i),progressString);
```

Update your code as follows...

```
  int i = 0;
  while(i < verseTitles.size()){

      String progressString = String.valueOf(progress);

      if(download.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){

          new DownloadVerses().execute(Mp3s.get(i), Titles.get(i),progressString);


              if(progress < 100){

                  if((progress + increment) > 100){
                      progress = 100;
                  }
                  else{
                      progress += increment;
                  }

              }
              i++;
      }     
  }
```

**Update:**

You can use `onProgressUpdate()` method to update progress update. For more details, you can see [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) document from Android Developer site.

Comment: With the code above, how I would check the status though? Because the download object doesn't exist. Also preferably I need the tasks to execute one after another (after the previous one has finished.)